# How to tell entitiy framework that my db context class is avaiable in core project to run the migration in diffrent project?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
Dear Developers,

I am new to EF.

I have this project srtucture. 

+ HrSoultion
    + <Application>   // namespace project
        - api // this is the mvc core project
   + <Core>   // namespace project
        - Entity// this is the project where I defined the models and db context class
```

Now I am confused where to run the add  Add-Migration HrSoultion.Core.HrSoultionContext

Thanks ?

Comment: Instead of running `Add-Migration`, I would recommend using the more modern [`dotnet ef` command line tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet).

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** Use command line

```
dotnet ef migrations add Init
```

**Option 2:** Select appropriate project before you run Add-Migration command in Package Manager Console. E.g.

[image]

Comment: what if I want to run it in the api project

Comment: As you described, your DBContext and entity classes are within Core project, so no need to run Add-Migration command in api project. Just in case if you are dealing with multiple databases with different projects entity classes than it's just matter of appropriate project/path selection. Hope that will clarify.

Comment: cleared boss as described